# What is the relation between image velocity, object velocity and mirror velocity?

Tags: optics, velocity

Suppositions used:
Velocity of image = V<sub>I</sub>
Velocity of object = V<sub>o</sub>
Velocity of mirror = V<sub>M</sub>

I Know the fact that 
 V<sub>I</sub>=-V<sub>o</sub> supposing mirror at rest 
and 
 V<sub>I</sub>=2V<sub>M</sub> supposing object at rest

Now considering both mirror and object in motion,
 V<sub>I</sub>=2V<sub>M</sub> - V<sub>o</sub> I ended up with this equation but my reference book suggests
 V<sub>I</sub>=2V<sub>M</sub> + V<sub>o</sub>
 I am stuck on this for last 4 hours. I searched over internet and found the same expression like that of mine in a youtube video, I did not find much reference on this topic though. Tried many ways but all ended up on this simple argument, which equation to follow?
Help

Comment: Read relative motion first ,clear your concepts and you are ready to go !

Comment: Your equation seems correct. do you have the reference to your book? or some other link that agrees with the other equation?

Comment: http://www.physicstutorials.org/home/optics/reflection-of-light/plane-mirrors-and-image-formation-in-plane-mirrors

Comment: @ Armando Esteban Quito I don't have any web reference of my book. That's the exact equation printed here and the team that wrote the book also taught the same thing during lecture.

Comment: @Pinku It would be a great help, if you could shed some more lights on it. Also, I did revise my relative motion concept.It provided evidence in my favor.

Comment: watch this it may help:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fR947XsR0Wo

Comment: @Pinku well thank you but i already had it watched. I have already searched over the internet to maximum limit of mine.When it did not help i have come here to seek help from humans directly. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt draw a picture!
Let's start with the positions first and then take the derivative to end up with the velocities.

[image]

Since the image and the object are at same distance from mirror,
$$x_i-x_m=x_m-x_o \implies x_i=2x_m-x_o$$
To make sure all the signs are correct I take $x_0=95,x_m=100$ and $x_i=105$. This gives $x_i=2\cdot100-95=200-95=105$. This formula seems correct.
Taking the derivative of both sides transforms every $x$ into a velocity
$$v_i=2v_m-v_0.$$
Taking $v_m=0$ gives $v_i=-v_o$ and taking $v_i=0$ gives $v_i=2v_m$. So why did the reference come up with something different? Maybe it was a typo or maybe they defined $v_i$ to be in the opposite way. If you define $v_i$ to be the velocity *towards* the mirror you'll get a plus sign. You would also get $v_i=v_0$ if the mirror isn't moving. Defining it this way can has some benefits. For example if the mirror is static both velocities are positive and you don't have to worry about minus signs but personally I like this definition better (you have to think less).

Answer (score 0):

I think that, since the velocities are in different directions, $2V_M -\left(-V_O\right) = 2V_M+V_O$.

Answer (score 0):

yeah the proper equation is 2Vm = Vi + Vo. now you need to choose an axis and put the proper sign for the two values. the equations will give you proper magnitudes and directions for the axis that you have chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I have considered an example and proved this formula in the image shown.

1. The first image has plane mirror and the person at rest.
2. Let us now consider the person velocity as $V_o=\frac{Unit Block(UB)}{second}$ towards the mirror and mirror velocity as $V_M=\frac{UB}{2}$ towards the person.
3. The second image shows the situation after one second. We see that image velocity is $V_I=2UB=2\frac{UB}{2}+UB$.
4. The third image considers the mirror velocity as $V_M=\frac{UB}{4}$ towards the person and the person velocity as $V_o=UB$ (see the third image with respect to first image). We see that the image velocity is $V_I=\frac{UB}{2}+UB=2\frac{UB}{4}+UB$.
5. From 3. and 4. points, we see that the formula is $V_I=2V_M+V_o$

[image: velocity of image]

Comment: An image may be useful. But it should always be complemented by some text. One of the reasons is that it is the only way to help visually impaired people.

Answer (score -1):

I think its for two cases
case I; when object and mirror moves along same direction Vi=2Vm -Vo

case II: when object and mirror are in motion in opposite direction Vi=2Vm + Vo